# move_uploaded_file hangs?

Tags: php, upload, flash, apache2

I seem to have a bizarre error I just can't quite figure out. My website was working on one server, but when I transferred it to a new one it stopped working. I believe I've narrowed the error down to this line of code:

```
$ret = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $orig_path);
```

This is executed through an AJAX call so it's a little bit tricky to debug, but the script can send back an error code and then my JavaScript will `alert` it. So, I've wrapped it in two of these debug statements:

```
echo json_encode(array(

    'success' => false,

    'errno' => $tmp_name.' -> '.$orig_path,

));

exit;



$ret = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $orig_path);



echo json_encode(array(

    'success' => false,

    'errno' => 'no error',

));

exit;
```

The first one works fine and spits out something like:

```
error /tmp/phpk3RICU -> /home/username/Websites/website/photos/o/2-4a3354dd017a9.jpg
```

Perhaps I'm a bit of a linux noob, but I can't actually find `/tmp/phpk3RICU` on my system (is it deleted as soon as the script exits or what?). More on that in a sec though.

If I delete the first debug check and let `move_uploaded_file` run, the 2nd debug check never seems to get executed, which leads me to believe move_uploaded_file is hanging.

If instead of using `$tmp_name` I use a file I *know* doesn't exist, then the 2nd check DOES get executed. So... it seems like it just doesn't want to move that tmp file, but it's not reporting an error.

I'm running a fresh install of the LAMP stack on my Unbutu machine, installed through apt-get... let me know if you need more info.

Oh.. and don't know if it's relevant, but the file gets uploaded through flash.

Comment: mkdir fails too actually... doesn't seem like to create files, and won't spit out an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. The problem was with permissions. 755 was enough on the other server, but not for this server it seems... not really sure why, I guess PHP is running under a different user? I'm not really sure how the whole permissions stuff works. What really boggles me is why `mkdir` and `move_uploaded_file` didn't fail and return false...

Answer (score 1):

Do you upload the file via the AJAX call?
Uploaded files are deleted as soon as the script you uploaded them to finishes executing - that's why you can't find it in /tmp.

Answer (score 1):

Try telling PHP to spit out all errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

It could be a configuration discrepancy that is breaking it on one of your servers. From the `move_uploaded_file()` [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) page:

> Note: `move_uploaded_file()` is both
> safe mode and `open_basedir` aware.
> However, restrictions are placed only
> on the destination path as to allow
> the moving of uploaded files in which
> filename may conflict with such
> restrictions. `move_uploaded_file()`
> ensures the safety of this operation
> by allowing only those files uploaded
> through PHP to be moved.